# bootable VHD created in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012

I created a Windows Server 2012 VHD using Hyper-V, host is also running WS2012, when I copy the VHD to my Win7 laptop and try to mount that VHD I'm unable to boot on that VHD. is there a way to convert this regular VHD to a bootable version?

Many thanks

Comment: booting and mounting are different things?  Are you trying to native boot the vhd file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VHD is already bootable, but your BCD store is unaware of its presence. Here are TechNet instructions for adding a VHD to your Windows 7 boot menu:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799299(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: followed the procedure, the mounted drive is empty which means I don't see any windows folder under the V:

Comment: Did you already install Windows 2012 into that VHD from your Hyper-V server? That was the understanding I had.